# 502 Bad Gateway - django + nginx + gunicorn - sock failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: django, nginx, permissions, gunicorn

I am following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

I believe everything else in my setup is correct. The file /var/log/nginx/error.log has many of the following error:

2015/12/19 18:41:58 [crit] 10850#0: *23 connect() to unix:/home/root/myproject/myproject.sock failed **(13: Permission denied)** while connecting to upstream, client: [[my ip]], server: [[server ip]], request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/root/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "[[server ip]]"

The command:

```
/home/root/myproject ls -l /home/root/classNote/classNote.sock
```

outputs:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data 0 Dec 19 18:17 /home/root/myproject/myproject.sock
```

EDIT: Andrei's comment's response:

the command:

```
ps ax | grep gunicorn
```

outputs:

```
  847 ?        Ss     0:00 /home/root/myproject/myprojectEnv/bin/python myprojectEnv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
  921 ?        S      0:00 /home/root/myproject/myprojectEnv/bin/python myprojectEnv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
  923 ?        S      0:00 /home/root/myproject/myprojectEnv/bin/python myprojectEnv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
  928 ?        S      0:00 /home/root/myproject/myprojectEnv/bin/python myprojectEnv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
 1136 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep gunicorn
```

Answer (score 5):

[link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67625668/14742746)

I just ran into this problem. I was able to create the gunicorn socket file, but nginx complained about permission denied. The issue was that my socket file was in a sub-folder and the root folder did not have read or execute permissions. So even though the sub-folder had the correct permissions, the root folder prevented nginx from entering the sub-folder.

The solution was to add read and execute permissions to the root folder:

```
chmod o+rx /example_root_folder
```

Comment: For people who are confused here. Go to your root folder, where you will see `~` in your terminal. Run this `chmod o+rx .`

Answer (score 3):

Seems there are permission issues start your nginx service as  root because root has permission to access your my project.sock

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Then

```
 sudo service nginx start
```

But it is not a good idea to start nginx as root. You may try changing permission of your current user

I can suggest you an alternative which works fine. 
Let a shell script handle all this. 
Create a shell script like this (* indicates required in comments)

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=""                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/path/to/django/project            # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/path/to/socket/file/myproject.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=                                      # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker   processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yourproject.settings             # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=yourproject.wsgi                     # WSGI module name (*)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /path/to/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Neither solution is working for me :( For your second solution, the only input I am unsure about is GROUP. I set it to www-data. When I run this file, I am still getting a 502 when I go to my ip.

Comment: Instead of www-data try this /etc/group and see group names my default group works for me

Answer (score -3):

I had a very similar problem like you before (also proceeded according to the mentioned tutorial on the digitalocean.com), by this I mean the socket was not working and also I was getting the 502 error.

The solution for me was to move from socket binding to binding a normal IP address.

Inside of a virtualenv (next to "manage.py") I have a gunicorn.py file: (NOTE: I use 3.4 version)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

"""
Run Gunicorn (Django) on a specific IP addr
"""

import os

# Change directory to the virtualenv folder
os.chdir("/home/your_path/name_of_env/")

# Run Gunicorn
os.system("bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 127.0.0.1:8000 your_project.wsgi:application &")
```

The script runs Gunicorn without activating the virtualenv (command "bin/gunicorn") and in background ("&").

NOTE: If you don't use virtualenv than remove "bin/" from the script above.

For calling that script after booting PC and login, add this line to your ".profile" file at the end. (It's inside your home directory)

```
python3.4 path/to/the/file/gunicorn.py
```

In a nginx file you should have this part of code:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Remember, the IP addr 127.0.0.1:8000 is reserved. So if you want to run Django developing server, you have 2 options:

1. Turn off Gunicorn by commands "ps aux | grep gunicorn" and "kill -9 [PID]" and then normally run a command "python3.4 manage.py runserver"
2. Or run Django developing server on a different IP and port, for example "python3.4 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"

This solution works for me.

Comment: You are suggesting to use django dev server. That is not meant for production. This discussion is for setting up a production environment.